# Three different results for $\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left((-\gamma+1)(v+e^\omega\frac{p^{\varepsilon+1}}{\varepsilon+1})\right)^{1/(-\gamma+1)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, problem-solving

I need to differentiate this equation wrt. $p$:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left((-\gamma+1)\left(v+e^\omega\frac{p^{\varepsilon+1}}{\varepsilon+1}\right)\right)^{1/(-\gamma+1)}$$

[See problem as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnN7Q.png)

My supervisor gets this result:

$$(-γ+1)^\frac{γ}{-γ+1}\left(v+e^{ω}\frac{p^{ε+1}}{ε+1}\right)^{\frac{γ}{-γ+1}}e^{ω}p^{ε+1}$$

[See supervisor's result as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rQCY.png)

Wolfram Alpha gets this result:

[See Wolfram Alphas result as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKqsw.png)

I get this result:

$$\left((-γ+1)e^{ω}\frac{p}{ε+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}-1}p^{ε+1}$$

[See my result as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUyRG.png)

Here are my calculations:

Steps:
1: Split up all parentheses (multiple inside and then add the potency of the outside parenthesis)

$$\frac{∂}{∂p}\left((-γ+1)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}v^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}+(-γ+1)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}e^{ω^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}}\frac{1}{ε+1}^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}} p^{\frac{ε+1}{-γ+1}}\right)$$

2: Remove $(-γ+1)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}v^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}$ as it is a constant

$$\frac{∂}{∂p}\left((-γ+1)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}e^{ω^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}}\frac{1}{ε+1}^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}} p^{\frac{ε+1}{-γ+1}}\right)$$

3: Use rule of derivatives (derivative wrt x: $x^n = nx^{n-1}$)

$$\left(\frac{ε+1}{-γ+1}\right)(-γ+1)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}e^{ω^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}}\frac{1}{ε+1}^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}p^{\frac{ε+1}{-γ+1}-1}$$

4: Convert the first fraction to factors by using potency rules and use the new form to multiply similar term's potences and isolate the part of the p that doesn't have the same potency in common (sorry if some terms sound strange, I didn't learn math in English)

$$(-γ+1)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}-1}e^{ω^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}}}\frac{1}{ε+1}^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}-1}p^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}-1}p^{ε+1}$$

5: Put all with same potency under same potency

$$\left((-γ+1)e^{ω}\frac{p}{ε+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{-γ+1}-1}p^{ε+1}$$

Which one is right? What did I do wrong? Any pointers to what method I should be using?

[See calculations as image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8yAU.png)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Latex this please

Comment: You can perform partial integration to verify

Comment: If you do not convert it to LaTex it is unreadable if you have to open many pictures.

Comment: Whoever gets this result should be right:
$$
(-\gamma+1)^\frac{\gamma}{-\gamma+1}\Big(\nu+e^\omega\frac{p^{\varepsilon+1}}{\varepsilon+1}\Big)^\frac{\gamma}{-\gamma+1}e^\omega p^\varepsilon\,.
$$

Comment: @Shaun Thanks, I'm doing it.

Comment: @Max0815 Done :)

Comment: @trula I see what you mean. I didn't know how to until now. So I did it :)

Comment: @KurtG. thank you. I would like to verify this. Not sure what either I or my supervisor did wrong.

Comment: @VictorNielsen . The image and your MathJax transcription disagree about what is inside the exponentiation with $1/(-y+1)$ . Is the front term $(-y+1)$ exponentiated or not ? Human errors all over the place. I usually help myself by numerically differentiating in python with some random inputs. Most importantly : Do you know the general mathematical principle that we apply when doing this differentiation ? If applied carefully nothing should go wrong.

Comment: When you ask if it's exponentiated, do you mean the result? And when you say the image and the mathjax disagree, I was not able to see find a difference between images and mathjax. Well the reason why the results are not the same is because some of us are doing a mistake. Supervisor or me or wolframalpha. Both me and supervisor gets that (-y+1) is differentiated, I just put it inside the parenthesis that is differentiated and he does not.  
I think my problem is that I know how to do xˆn -> nxˆn-1, but I don't know how to do (a+bx^c)^(d).

Comment: @KurtG. Forgot to add your @.

Comment: @VictorNielsen do you know the chain rule ? I mean not the result but the function we are differentiating . Image and mathjax disagree .  Count the parentheses .

Comment: @KurtG. Yes I see now. Corrected. I know the chain rule. Not sure how it applies here since there is just one function.

Comment: @VictorNielsen Hint about chain rule: Two functions !
\begin{align}
h(x)&=((-\gamma+1)\,x)^\frac{1}{-\gamma+1}\,,\\
g(p)&=\nu+e^\omega\frac{p^{\varepsilon+1}}{\varepsilon+1}\,.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

I solved it through @KurtG. 's help. Just needed to use the chain rule:

[image]

Comment: In the last line there is again a parenthesis missing.

Comment: @KurtG. Indeed. Fixed.

Comment: Good. This agrees with Wolfram Alpha's result.